# What is the output impedence of this RC Circuit

Tags: impedance

I have this simple circuit. And from what I calculated the output impedance seen from the OUT node comes to about \$138.765 \Omega\$.

$$ X_c = \frac{1}{2\pi * 890*10^3 * 10^{-9}} = 178.8257\Omega $$
$$ Z_{out} = R2||X_c = \frac{220 * 178.8257}{\sqrt{220^2 + 178.8257^2}} = 138.765\Omega$$
[image]

With an input of 890K Hz sine wave of 2v pk-pk, the voltage at OUT node comes to is about 1.2615v pk-pk.

If I connect a resister of the same value of \$138.765 \Omega\$, the voltage at OUT node should be half ed.

[image]

But I see a voltage of 697.843mV instead of 630mV. What is the problem, am I calculating the output impedance wrongly?

Comment: Since you have a reactive component (the capacitor) in there, the output impedance is a complex number. In order to test this, you need a similar load impedance -- one that also includes a reactive component.

Comment: How did you arrive at \$\approx 138\Omega\$?

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks, I see. But why is the output 697mv?

Comment: Because you have failed to account for the phase shifts, which are different with/without the load resistor.

Comment: Z= R+Jwc wc= capacitive reactance complex conjugate of impedance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what was wrong.

Without the load resistor, the impedance seen at the OUT node is a complex number.
$$\dfrac{1}{Z_{out}} = \dfrac{1}{R2} + \dfrac{j}{X_c} $$ Thus,
$$ Z_{out} = 87.527 - j107.678\Omega$$

With that Load resistor of 138.765 \$\Omega\$, the total impedance of the circuit becomes,
$$ Z_{total} = 138.765 + 87.527 - j107.678$$
$$= 226.292 - j107.678\Omega$$
$$|Z_{total}| = 250.604 \Omega $$

If the unloaded voltage at the OUT node is 1.26v, then, the voltage at the OUT node with the LOAD resistor is a simple voltage divider, and

$$V_{out} = \dfrac{1.26 \cdot 138.765}{|Z_{total}|} $$
$$V_{out} = \dfrac{1.26 \cdot 138.765}{ 250.604} = 697.68mV. $$

The answer checks out, with acceptable error.

Answer (score 5):

The output impedance can be calculated from 1/(1/Xc + 1/R)

Xc = \$1 \over j\omega C \$

R = 220\$\Omega\$

The admittances add in quadrature since one is imaginary and the other is real- 
It is easy to show(tm) that the magnitude of the impedance Z is as follows:

|Z| = \$ R \cdot (\frac {1}{\omega C})  \over \sqrt{R^2 + \frac {1}{\omega^2 C^2}}\$

That is the reason you are seeing a higher voltage than you expect. The situation will be different again with the added resistor, so you have to consider the above equation with the two resistors effectively in parallel.

Comment: I thought |Z| = (Xc*R)/sqrt(R^2 + Xc^2).

Comment: @ArjobMukherjee Thanks, fixed. I'd prefer not to write Xc here, because the problem is coming up from ignoring that Xc is imaginary, and Xc is used both ways.

Comment: That is how I have calculated the impedance. How do I account for the phase shift?

Comment: If you're just measuring the voltage, the phase is of no importance, but as I said you have to add the admittances in quadrature, so use the capacitive reactance and the Thevenin equivalent resistance (the two in parallel).

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what In-phase and quadrature components are. Can you suggest a book or something?

Comment: To solve steady state output all you need to do is to apply the usual Ohm's law and voltage divider formulas using complex numbers (inductors and capacitors have imaginary impedance, resistors real, and combinations generally have components that are real and imaginary. When you have the voltage in complex terms you can do a coordinate conversion from rectangular to polar coordinates to find the amplitude (and phase angle if you need it). See any math book that covers complex analysis. We used **Basic Complex Analysis (Marsden)** back in Uni but that's probably too deep for your needs now.